# Validating form (cross-field) without entity using methods (assert true/false) in symfony2

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have a registration form that isn't tied to any entity. I figured out how to specify the validators (`validation_constraint` option). It's okay if I use simple validators.

But what if I want to make a cross-field validation, like comparing the "password" and "repeat password" fields?

If it was an entity then it would be as simple as adding an "@Assert/True" annotation to a custom method, but here I am clueless, can't find anything in the docs or the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `buildForm` function of the form you can use the `CallbackValidator` :

```
 use Symfony\Component\Form as Form;

 //...

 public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
 {
    // build your form...
    $builder->addValidator(new Form\CallbackValidator(function(Form\FormInterface $form)
    {
       if ($form["password"]->getData() != $form["repeat_password"]->getData())
       {
            $form->addError(new Form\FormError('passwords must be the same'));
       }
    });
    //...
 }
```

In symfony 2.1+ you should add an event listender for POST_BIND event:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_BIND, function(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if($form['password']->getData() !== $form['password_confirm']->getData())
    {
        $form['password_confirm']->addError(new FormError('error.form.passwords-not-match'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. It's not so nice as using entity methods but works flawlessy and most importantly does not try to work around symfony.